# Data Analysis having weekly and yearly seasonality

Tags: time-series, forecasting, seasonality, tbats

I have 2 years of daily data of demand of some product. I can observe daily as well as yearly seasonality. I did run decompose method(frequency = 365) to separate data into trend, seasonal and random components. I am interested in getting random data but it gives almost constant random component.

Then I did use TBATS model with multiple frequency (7,365) and getting level,scope,season1,season2 components separately. Can i get the random component from this ?

Actual problem is I want to find significance of one variable on demand but seasonality dominates that and i am not getting any correlation. So i am trying to find correlation from the random data ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "random" component in a decomposition is the remainder from subtracting trend+season from y. So in the TBATS model, the residuals are the equivalent.

Comment: Thank U very much ...  plz clarify one thing,  I want to find price change effect on the random data ( Residuals(tbats)) ..  In the whole data, i am getting only seasonality effect ....Am i going in right way ??